# SAS Error importing a csv file from a J path to the sas server (opt/sas), changing its delimiter

Tags: csv, sas, delimiter

I'm trying to automatically change the delimiter of a csv file that is in a certain path (in J:, the local server of my company) and leave it in the SAS server.

It turns out that when I run this code it works for me:

```
data _null_;
infile "/opt/sas/data/xxx/xx/xx/Folder1/xxxx.csv" dlm='|' dsd length=ll column=cc truncover ENCODING='utf-8';
file "/opt/sas/data/xxx/xxx/xxx/Folder1/Source/xxxx.csv" dlm='|' ;
do until(cc>ll);
input value ~ :$char32767. @;
if missing(value) then value ='""';
put value :$char32767. @;
end;
put;
run;
```

Since I take the csv file from a folder in J and put it in another folder in J like that, doesnt works:

```
data _null_;
infile "J:\xxxx\xxx\xxxxx\xxxxx.csv" dlm='|' dsd length=ll column=cc truncover ENCODING='utf-8';
file "/opt/sas/data/xxxx/xx/xxx/Folder1/Source/xxxx.csv" dlm='|' ;
do until(cc>ll);
input value ~ :$char32767. @;
if missing(value) then value ='""';
put value :$char32767. @;
end;
put;
run;
```

The problem comes when I put a route in the infile that is in "J:", I get this error:

```
ERROR: Invalid open mode.
```

and this too:

```
ERROR: Some code points were not transcoded. SAS
ERROR: Some code points were not transcoded. SAS
ERROR: Some code points were not transcoded. SAS
```

But these I think is because of the encoding, even though I am saying that the encoding has to be utf-8. But I think the problem lies in the path and the invalid open error

Can someone shed some light on this for me? If you know another way to try to do what I'm doing with another method in SAS let me know, but I'm trying to automate the transformation of certain csvs in a flow and I need this step.

Thank you very much in advance, greetings!

Comment: You are using SAS on a server via Enterprise Guide or SAS Studio? Can the server even reach the network path which is J: on your Desktop? Also, probably this path is not mounted as drive J: on the server and you have to use the absolute path.

Comment: On Unix your filenames have to start with `/` or else they are considered relative from the current working directory.  Drive letters do not mean anything on Unix machines.

Comment: How do I know what my absolute path is?

Comment: I changed the bars of my path but it still doesn't work

Comment: You should ask your IT where the drive J: that you can access from your desktop is mounted on the SAS server which is probably running on Linux. They should be able to tell you the path.